# Sort with no repeat in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, c++11

I am a beginner in C++. I typed a simple code to sort an integer array, but I couldn't figure out how to handle same elements like if I enter 1,12,3,5,11,3
output is given as **1,3,3,5,11,12** but I want the output to be ***1,3,5,11,12***.
What should I add further in the loop I've coded?

```
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{

    for(int j=i+1;j<len;j++)
    {

        if(array[i]>array[j])
        {
            swap = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = swap;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Once it's sorted, eliminate duplicates: compare each element to the next, and if they are equal, eliminate one of them.

Comment: `std::sort` and `std::unique` already exist.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to write it by yourself, do as they told you in comments.

If you just want to have a sorted list without duplicates, use std::set and insert all your numbers inside. You will get a sorted, unique list of ints.

Answer (score 2):

It may be easier for you to understand this solution:

```
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{

    for(int j=i+1;j<len;j++)
    {

        if(array[i]>array[j])
        {
            swap = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = swap;
        }
    }
}

cout<<array[0];
for(int i=1; i<len; ++i)
{
    if(array[i] != array[i-1])
    {
        cout<<array[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: UB if len == 0, and array still has duplicated elements.

Answer (score 1):

Normal way :

Remove the duplicates from the array that you've sorted

```
int *start = array;
int *end = array+len;
int *res = start;

while (++start != end) {
     if (!(*res == *start)) {
          *(++res) = *start;
        }
    }

int new_len=++res -array;
```

Else why not simply use STL ?

```
std::sort(array,array+len);
int *res=std::unique(array,array+len);
int new_len=res -array;
```